# Linux pipe mysql CLI "show variables" to text file

Tags: mysql, linux

Relative Linux newbie here but I can't believe how much I'm struggling with this simple thing:

In shell, at a mysql prompt (version 5.6.xx):

```
mysql> show variables;
```

great, it blasts a ton of information to the console.  I need it to pipe to a file instead.  I've tried various (old) suggestions I found on the interwebs...no joy.

How do I get the result of this command to end up written to a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go.

```
mysql < commands.txt > output.txt
```

where `commands.txt` is a file containing

```
show variables;
```

And the output should end up in the `output.txt` file

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the "-e" option like this:

```
mysql -uyour_user_name -pyour_passwd -e "show variables;" > ./mysql_variables.txt
```

Comment: Any idea how we can use the txt file which we generated to import the settings into a different server ?