# Linux pipe to text file shows unwanted special characters in text editor

Tags: linux, symfony, terminal

my
`symfony help >> ./symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh;`
looks encrypted for me.

#### result looks in Kate editor like so:

```
[32mSymfony CLI[39m version [33mv4.25.4[39m (c) 2017-2021 Symfony SAS
...
```

#### expected the same formation like i know it from terminal:

```
Symfony CLI version v4.25.4 (c) 2017-2021 Symfony SAS
...
```

##### source i readet:

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428967/linux-pipe-mysql-cli-show-variables-to-text-file

- [Pitest: How to redirect the log output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109803/pitest-how-to-redirect-the-log-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Those aren't encryption, they're cursor motion or color changes.

Comment: Most full-screen programs detect when the output is being piped and disable features like that. Apparently `symfony` is not that smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various console apps either default to showing with Ansi terminal codes, or without. The Symfony console command has a `--no-ansi` option to turn it off.

An issue at https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/222 also suggested the env var `NO_COLOR`, which does also work.

```
NO_COLOR=1 symfony list
```